# why would changes to the Ref object trigger rerender in this code

Tags: reactjs, react-native

as shown in the react-native animation demo on https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated

```
  const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current  // Initial value for opacity: 0

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(
      fadeAnim,
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 10000,
      }
    ).start();
  }, [fadeAnim])

  return (
    <Animated.View                 // Special animatable View
      style={{
        ...props.style,
        opacity: fadeAnim,         // Bind opacity to animated value
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
}
```

the changes to the fadeAnim would trigger rerender of the component, which I don't understand.
the react documentation never mentions the ref object is part of state either.

am I missing something?

Comment: Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render, I guess Animated.View does something special to bind the render to animated value

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but I think it will still work even if you remove `fadeAnim` in the dependency of `useEffect`. I never tried using refs as a dependency of hooks before and it works as expected.